# Sharpmap - Print points over map

Tags: c#, winforms, gis, sharpmap, geoapi

I've just started using Sharpmap but I have a problem. I'm not able to print points (not even one) over a map using this library.

I didn't find a good example to do it, and my code is not working. It draws a point way too far from where it should be (Madrid, Spain).

I would appreciate some help if someone knows how to use it.

Here is my code :

```
namespace TestsSharpmapForm
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        VectorLayer vlay = new VectorLayer("Spain");
        vlay.DataSource = new SharpMap.Data.Providers.ShapeFile(@"ESP_adm_shp\ESP_adm2.shp", true);

        VectorLayer vlay2 = new VectorLayer("Points");
        Collection<GeoAPI.Geometries.IGeometry> geomColl =   new Collection<GeoAPI.Geometries.IGeometry>();
        //Get the default geometry factory
        GeoAPI.GeometryServiceProvider.Instance = new NetTopologySuite.NtsGeometryServices();
        GeoAPI.Geometries.IGeometryFactory gf =
            GeoAPI.GeometryServiceProvider.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory();

        geomColl.Add(gf.CreatePoint(new GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate(40.4177623, -3.6690416)));
        vlay2.DataSource = new SharpMap.Data.Providers.GeometryProvider(geomColl);

        mapBox1.Map.Layers.Add(vlay);
        mapBox1.Map.Layers.Add(vlay2);

        //ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.Transformations.CoordinateTransformationFactory ctFact = new ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.Transformations.CoordinateTransformationFactory();
        //vlay.CoordinateTransformation = ctFact.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.GeographicCoordinateSystem.WGS84, ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.ProjectedCoordinateSystem.WebMercator);
        //vlay.ReverseCoordinateTransformation = ctFact.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.ProjectedCoordinateSystem.WebMercator, ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.GeographicCoordinateSystem.WGS84);


        mapBox1.Map.ZoomToExtents();
        mapBox1.Refresh();
        mapBox1.ActiveTool = SharpMap.Forms.MapBox.Tools.Pan;
        Image imgMap = mapBox1.Map.GetMap();


    }

    private void mapBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X and Y should be the other way round:

```
geomColl.Add(gf.CreatePoint(new GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate(-3.6690416, 40.4177623)));
```

Comment: Well the lat lon order is a common confusion and actually SharpMap's order is consideren incorrect by many. https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Axis_Order_Confusion